# Is it possible to have a generic shared pipeline in Azure DevOps pull request build across multiple repos?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-repos

The requirement is to have AZDO run some bash commands during a PR. The source and target branch of the PR are used in the bash commands. This is to be executed during PRs for almost all repos in the project.

**What I'm doing currently**

1. Create a template for the pipeline (the template is in a standalone utility repo)
2. In each of my repo, create a yaml file that uses the template
3. Create a pipeline for each repo which uses the yaml that was created
4. Add the pipeline to the respective branches' PR policy

This works as expected, but I have to create and maintain multiple pipelines which are essentially doing the same thing.

**What I've tried**

1. Create a template for the pipeline (the template is in a standalone utility repo)
2. In the same repo as the template, create a yaml file that uses the template
3. Create a pipeline which uses the yaml that was created, pointing to the utility repo
4. Add the pipeline to the respective branches' PR policy

The issue with my attempt was that the PR build with this pipeline wouldn't run because it does not stem from the same repository of the PR branches.

**My question**

Is there a way to accomplish this without creating a pipeline for each of my repo just so that it would be able to run in a PR build?

Comment: Are you asking for single pipeline (somewhere), referencing your template, that triggers on any of your repos, building that repo?

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole Yes I'm asking for a single pipeline referencing my template. But specifically, I want it to trigger during PR of any of my repos. Just to be clear, the pipeline is not doing a build, but rather, a series of bash commands.